How should I scale these faces facing each direction towards the center?
I am trying to scale the faces marked in Pic01 towards the center by using the Scale tool; however, as you may see from Pic02, the circled piece doesn't work as expected.


I would much appricate if anyone could explain this to me or tell me how should I deal with it!

You're trying to scale them with the Move tool? What direction are you expecting them to move?

I mean Scale tool (press s); wanna move them towards the center.

Set your transform pivot point to 3D Cursor.


Then, scale those faces excluding the Z-axis.S, SHIFT + Z, 0.

Thank you, but didnt work

Perhaps I misunderstood you.  Are you trying to seal the hole, or just slightly move everything in?

And what is the face you have circled not doing that you want it to?
